# Fix $1 \le k \le n$. How many integer sequences $1 \le a_1 < a_2 < ··· < a_k \le n$ satisfy $a_i \equiv i$ (mod 2) for all $i = 1, 2, . . . , k$?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Fix $1 \le k \le n$. How many integer sequences $1  \le  a_1 < a_2 < ··· < a_k \le n$ satisfy $a_i \equiv i$ (mod 2)  for all $i = 1, 2, . . . , k$?

So I want to find the number of integer sequences that satisfy the above. I find the problem is equivalent to finding the number of integer sequences with patterns like {odd, even, odd, ...} from $1$ to $n$, but I'm stumped here.

Any hints and/or tips would be very much welcome.

Comment: Hint: let $x_i=a_{i+1}-a_i$. How many ways are there to choose the values of $x_i$ so they are odd nonnegative integers summing to $n$?

Comment: Why not calculate it for a few small values of $k$ and $n$ and then look it up in the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences?

Comment: Making any progress, HAL?

Comment: Given up? Too bad.